# Chrome 80: Pause script execution (F8) does not work when DevTools is not focused

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

since Chrome 80 I cannot pause the script execution when the focus is on the website I'm developing. This is extremely inconvenient e.g. when debugging hover effects.

Does anyone else experience this issue or has more information about it? Maybe a feature flag deep inside the browser settings?

**Update**

This was fixed in Chrome 83.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. There's no setting.

Comment: Super annoying. Can't work w/o this :-)

Comment: Go to the bugreport below, log in with your google account and click on the star (top left) to show that you want this fixed asap.

Comment: Has this stopped working again with Chrome 90?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in Chrome, I found the bugreport here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1049910&q=f8&can=2

Answer (score 29):

Until it is fixed, you can use the following in your app:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 119) { // F8
        debugger;
    }
}, {
    capture: true
});
```

Comment: can also be pasted in the devtools console!

Answer (score 5):

**WORKAROUND**

You can use option *Break on -> subtree modifications*

It helps me to stop script execution instead of using f8 functionality.

Steps:
1. Turn on 'Break on' for element you need to debug
2. Make some changes (hover or open drop down list as in my situation)
3. Browser will pause script execution

[image: I turn on this for debugged element]

Answer (score -5):

Use Ctrl+\ to pause the debugger. It works.